# Branching and Merging pcollection list in Apache Beam from common input

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm building a dataflow pipeline and I'm having some trouble branching and merging outputs. The pipeline I want to build is as follows:

1. Read some input data `input_data`.
2. A. Extract some metric, `metric_1`, on `input_data`.
   B. Extract some other metric, `metric_2`, on `input_data`
3. Since these metric extractions are computationally expensive, I want to branch off of the main `input_data` and merge the outputs afterwards for further calculation. Merge outputs `output`.

Here's some sample code that encapsulates my actual pipeline

```
class ReadData(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        # read from source
        return [{'input': np.random.rand(100,10)}]


class GetFirstMetric(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        # some processing
        return [{'first': np.random.rand(100,4)}]


class GetSecondMetric(beam.DoFn):
    def process(self, element):
        # some processing
        return [{'second': np.random.rand(100,3)}]


def run():
    with beam.Pipeline() as p:
        input_data = (p | 'read sample data' >> beam.ParDo(ReadData()))

        metric_1 = (input_data | 'some metric on input data' >> beam.ParDo(GetFirstMetric()))
        metric_2 = (input_data | 'some aggregate metric' >> beam.ParDo(GetSecondMetric()))

        output = ((metric_1, metric_2) 
                  | beam.Flatten()
                  | beam.combiners.ToList()
                  | beam.Map(print)
        )
```

When I run this, I get a `'PBegin' object has no attribute 'windowing'` error. I've seen some examples and sample code for doing something like this in Java. But I couldn't find the right resources for doing the same in Python. My question is as follows:

1. What's the right way to branch and merge pcollections (especially if the branches came from a common input)?
2. Is there a better pipeline design for accomplishing the same?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this code, your problem is that you are not 'starting' an initial PCollection. In `ReadData.process` - what is the value of the variable `element`?

Well, the runner can't come up with a value, because there's no input pcollection. You need to create your first PCollection. You'd do something like the following code...

As for making them into a list - perhaps a side input strategy may work. CAn you try the following:

```
def run():
    with beam.Pipeline() as p:
        starter_pcoll = p | beam.Create(['any'])
        input_data = (starter_pcoll | 'read sample data' >> beam.ParDo(ReadData()))

        metric_1 = (input_data | 'some metric on input data' >> beam.ParDo(GetFirstMetric()))
        metric_2 = (input_data | 'some aggregate metric' >> beam.ParDo(GetSecondMetric()))

        side_in = beam.pvalue.AsList((metric_1, metric_2) 
                                     | beam.Flatten())

        p | beam.Create(['any']) | beam.Map(lambda x, si: print(si),
                                            side_in)
```

This should make your pipeline run. Happy to clarify about your specific questions further.

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. That absolutely fixed it for the problem detailed in the question. But my original pipeline (following a similar outline as described in the question) gets stuck at the `beam.combiners.ToList()` step forever (or at least it doesn't print anything at all). However, when I print the output of `beam.Flatten()`, I see both the pcollections. Any suggestions on how I can fix/debug this will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Yup, I figured your real questions was something else. How large are your elements?

Comment: Shape of Metric1 array: (600, 400)
Shape of Metric2 array: (50000,)
Is there a better/efficient way to combine arrays this size?

Comment: Do you know their approximate sizes in bytes? I've proposed side inputs. Can you try that? (see my code snippet)